# How to input values in monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I want to input values in monkeyrunner,such as input username,password to login my application.but I don't know how to do it,I just only know how to touch and press.
thanks for your help.

Comment: nobody answer my question ? nobody use monkeyrunner to test application ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `device.type("Username")`

```
device.type("password")
```

You can input the values in monkeyrunner. Which letter do u want to type that string u can be give as a argument of `type("string")`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to input values using monkeyrunner.

The first is to use the `press` function of the MonkeyDevice class to send key event specified by type to the key specified by keycode (see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html#press). By this way, you can send all key events contained in Android.view.KeyEvent. For example, if you want to input the number key 8, you can use `device.press('KEYCODE_8', 'DOWN_AND_UP')`.

However, if you just want to input strings such as a username or a password, it is convenient to use the `type` function such as `device.type("username")`.